# Finding Probability in a Certain Time

Tags: probability

Consider Kuldeep purchase a product of company $X.$ The manual on it states that the lifetime $T$ of product is defined as the amount of time (in years) the product works properly until breaks down, satisfy the following equation

$P\left ( T\geq t \right )=e^{-\frac{t}{4}}$ for all $t\geq 0$

The probability that it breaks down in $3rd$ year is __________________

---

What to use poisson or exponential distribution?

As this question uses exponential distribution for a particular minute(https://gateoverflow.in/304471/grewal?show=316048), I thought because of third year(a particular year) , it also use exponential distribution.

But, in answer it is given a certain range $P(2\leq X \leq3)=e^{-2/4}-e^{-3/4}$

Why such calculation required here?

Comment: Use exponential distribution

Comment: The third year starts when the product is two years old and ends when the product is three years old.

Comment: What will be mean here?

Comment: @saulspatz Can u elaborate it more??

Answer (score 1):

The lifetime $T$ of product is defined as the amount of time (in years) the product works properly until breaks down, satisfying the following equation

$P\left ( T\geq t \right )=e^{-\frac{t}{4}}$ for all $t\geq 0$

So, $T$ follows Exponential distribution with mean $4$.

Now,the probability that it breaks down in $3rd$ year is :
$P(T \leq3)-P(T>2)$
$=P(2 \leq T \leq3)$
$=e^{-2/4}-e^{-3/4}$